# What is the max byte size that can be transferred in one package via http(s)?

Tags: http, browser, request, size

so as far as I understand when there is a `GET` request, the data is send from the server to the browser in multiple packages, depending on the size of the request.

I am wondering how much bytes fit into one package. I am pretty sure I read this somewhere once, but I can not find the reference.

Also does this differ from http to https?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean IP package? For IPv4 the maximum size is 576 bytes while for IPv6 its 1280 bytes. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

It doesn't depend on the protocol as long as it is transmitted over IP.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I did, but I wasn't sure it is actually the same. So if I have for e.g. an icon with 500 bytes sizes ti would be transferred within one package, correct?

Comment: @LukasOppermann Maybe. That would leave 74 bytes for HTTP headers (2 reserved for `\r\n`). For example `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is already 17 bytes (with invisible `\r\n` at the end). Also `Content-Length` header is mandatory. But why are you worried about that to begin with?

Comment: Ahh, okay, so I have to account for this as well. I guess there is no precise number anywhere how many bytes a file can have to be delivered in one package with a 200 header? I guess cookies and all this will also count against this limit.

Comment: Maximum 576b for an IPv4 packet ??? The packet size in IPv4 is represented on 2 bytes so it is 64KB max. But it is greatly dependent on the underlying transmission layer. Actually 576b is the _minimum_ packet size a IPv4 compliant device is supposed to accept

Comment: It is more from an academical point of view. I am trying to figure out if there would be a way to deliver a websites above the fold within one package to get an basically instant load (minus the latency, etc. for the one request).

Comment: Good luck to you then, HTTP (1.x) has never been designed for performance. HTTP 2.0 is the way to go.

Comment: Using http2 would not be a problem. It is pretty well supported already.

Comment: @Guillaume Read the article: `The Internet Protocol requires that hosts must be able to process IP datagrams of at least 576 bytes` More is optional, thus not safe.

Comment: @freakish: you will not find any real device that is able to run a web browser but is not able to handle a IPv4 packet of 577 to 1500 bytes. The real limit is actually at the data link level. If you do the test of capturing a network trace for this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522505/what-is-the-max-byte-size-that-can-be-transferred-in-one-package-via-https/40522756#40522756), you will see that the GET request is in a 747bytes IP packet, and the response is in a 639bytes packet (using Firefox at the time I write this, numbers may vary depending on the headers, cookies, etc.)...

Comment: @Guillaume Can you gurantee that every device is capable of handling ipv4 packets greater then 576 bytes? Or that router you are sending to is capable of doing that? By the standard each device is permitted to silently discard ipv4 packets greater then 576 bytes. I don't care about testing my local machine. That does not mean anything.

Comment: Not to mention that a data link limit might be even smaller then that of network's limit (and thus fragmentation on data link layer occurs).

Comment: You are talking about the theory from a 1981 standard (IPv4) (and you are 100% right), I am talking about real life in 2016 where MTUs less than 1400 bytes are oddities (if they exist at all). This debate is worthless.

Comment: It is not "theory" but standard. So what that it is from 1981? Completely unrelated. Again, if you believe that it is no longer valid (i.e. that all devices can handle more data) then please provide some evidence. Otherwise you are just talking .

Answer (score 0):

That greatly depends on what you are talking about when you say "package". At the application level, there is no limit to the size of the HTTP response body. It will be divided into chunks but that is transparent if you use a decent HTTP abstraction library.

And no, it does not differ between HTTP and HTTPS (which are basically the same protocol, the later having a SSL layer added between the HTTP and TCP layers).

If you want to develop your own library:  [the "chunked" transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) part of the RFC does not define a limit for the chunk size. But transmitting relatively small sized chunks (one that can fit in a single IP packet) instead of very large ones (which would have to be split at the network layer anyway) seems reasonable.